# Translation of my name

Tags: translation

My name is Joe Tailor. I tried to translate it to Japanese and got this: ジョーテーラー

Is this accurate? Or are there inaccuracies like it being “Joe Taylor” for example? It has to be with an “i” please. Thank you.

Comment: Transcriptions of foreign names into Japanese are *phonetic*. 'Joe Taylor' and 'Joe Tailor' are going to look the exact same.

Comment: FWIW, Tailor/Taylor is more likely written as テイラー instead of テーラー.

Comment: Depending on where / how you need the translation, you may want to add a <space> or a "small solid sphere, being larger and located higher than a normal dot" [sorry for bad explanation] between the name and surname to indicate that it is a full name and tell where the given and and family name starts. Also for others than you, although Los Angeles is spelled ロサンゼルス , POTUS #2 whose name was John Adams, would get his name translated to "ジョン・アダムズ" (here was the dot I meant) or "ジョン アダムズ" but not "ジョナダムズ"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ジョー・テーラー is one correct spelling with the middle dot or interpunct added.  テイラー can also be a spelling based on personal preference. After researching the most common spellings of both names, I realized that the name Tailor is considered a profession, spelled the same way, and that indicates the way it would be spelled as was indicated in the question. The name Taylor however, is more commonly recognized as a first or last name. The two terms are written differently to reflect the difference between the profession or the name Tailor, and the name Taylor. The difference in spelling is determined by the user.

Comment: The name Taylor can get rendered as either テイラー or テーラー, so looking at the Japanese spelling can't tell you what the English spelling was.

Comment: Tailor is spelled the same way as the profession. Taylor is a first or last personal name. The OP addressed the spelling difference.

Comment: I'm aware of the difference in English. I'm saying that Japanese doesn't maintain that difference the way you implied it does. People with the name "Taylor" are not always テイラー in Japanese. Sometimes they are テーラー, even though that is usually used for representing "Tailor."

Comment: I looked at the most common spellings.

Comment: Personal preference can also have sway here, even legally.  For example, I knew an "Alex" who preferred to write his name アレクッス instead of the traditional spelling アレックス...  It even showed up on his official documents spelled like that.

Comment: The OP has indicated a personal preference.

Comment: This Alex also said that he regretted his choice, because it tripped up Japanese people all the time.  He didn't have the greatest grasp of the language when he first went to the official channels, and It got stuck that way.  No one corrected him...

Comment: His expressed preference is for it to not be mistaken for "Taylor" when written in Japanese. The fact that Taylor can be written both ways means that it's not possible to prevent that assumption with certainty, though using テーラー makes it more likely that people will assume it's Tailor and not Taylor.

Comment: everyone feel free to edit my post